# application:handleActionWithIdentifier: not called

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

I am trying to detect when a user taps on the notification message in the application. However, this delegate is never called.

I am using Xcode 7.3.1. In SDK this method is not deprecated. But on Apple API site, [it is deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623068-application?language=objc).

Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me when i changed the   action.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background to 
  action.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Foreground

background to foreground